# Simple flood fill algorithm in C to fill an array of integers

Tags: python, c, algorithm, queue, flood-fill

After trying my luck at [implementing it in Fortran 90](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287543/flood-fill-algorithm-in-fortran-90), I turned to C. I'm not sure whether it's my `queue` implementation or the actual `flood fill algorithm` but it doesn't work as expected and tends to fill the whole array, irrespective of any border I'm putting in it's way. My goal is to create a `Python` extension.

Below is the code, which is based on `scikit-image`'s implementation of this algorithm.
The initial intent was to implement the `queue` as a dynamic array and borrow the code from [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Queue/Definition#Dynamic_array) but I couldn't make it work either so I've tried to make it more like `scikit-image`'s `QueueWithHistory` implementation, although with minor adjustments.

`queue.h`

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

typedef size_t DATA; /* type of data to store in queue */
typedef struct {
    DATA *buf;
    size_t head;
    size_t tail;
    size_t alloc;
} queue_t, *queue;

extern queue init_queue();
extern void free_queue(queue q);
extern void push_queue(queue q, DATA *n);
extern unsigned char pop_queue(queue q, DATA *n);

#endif /* QUEUE_H */
```

`queue.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "queue.h"


#define QUEUE_INIT_SIZE 64
#define QUEUE_THRESHOLD 512


static void _handle_memory_allocation_failure(const char *message, queue q) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to (re)allocate memory for %s\n", message);
    free_queue(q);  // Ensure proper cleanup
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

queue init_queue() {
    queue q = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
    if (!q) {
        _handle_memory_allocation_failure("queue structure", NULL);
    }
    q->buf = malloc(sizeof(DATA) * (q->alloc = QUEUE_INIT_SIZE));
    if (!q->buf) {
        _handle_memory_allocation_failure("queue buffer", q);
    }
    q->head = q->tail = 0;
    return q;
}

void free_queue(queue q) {
    if (!q) return;
    free(q->buf);
    free(q);
}

static void _grow_queue(queue q) {
    q->alloc *= 2;
    DATA *new_buf = realloc(q->buf, sizeof(DATA) * q->alloc);
    if (!new_buf) {
        _handle_memory_allocation_failure("growing queue buffer", q);
    }
    q->buf = new_buf;
}

void push_queue(queue q, DATA *n) {
    if (q->alloc <= q->head) {
        _grow_queue(q);
    }
    q->buf[q->head++] = *n;
}

unsigned char pop_queue(queue q, DATA *n) {
    if (q->tail < q->head) {
        *n = q->buf[q->tail++];
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`floodfill.h`

```
#ifndef FLOODFILL_H
#define FLOODFILL_H

// Function declarations
int flood_fill(int* image, int* offsets, size_t n_offsets,
               size_t start_index, int new_value, size_t image_size);

#endif /* FLOODFILL_H */
```

`floodfill.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "floodfill.h"
#include "queue.h"


// C implementation of floodfill algorithm

int flood_fill(int* image, int* offsets, size_t n_offsets,
               size_t start_index, int new_value, size_t image_size) {
    
    size_t current_index, neighbor_index;

    // Get the seed value (image value at start location)
    int seed_value = image[start_index];
    // Short circuit to avoid infinite loop
    if (seed_value == new_value) {
        return 0;
    }
    image[start_index] = new_value;
    // Initialize the queue and push start position
    queue q = init_queue();
    push_queue(q, &start_index);
    
    // Break loop if all queued positions were evaluated
    while (pop_queue(q, &current_index)) {
        // Look at all neighbors
        for (int i = 0; i < n_offsets; ++i) {
            neighbor_index = current_index + offsets[i];
            if (neighbor_index < image_size) {
                if (image[neighbor_index] == seed_value) {
                    // Process neighbor and push to queue
                    image[neighbor_index] = new_value;
                    push_queue(q, &neighbor_index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Ensure memory is released
    free_queue(q);
    return 0;
}
```

The above C code is wrapped in a Python module, below is the main function that calls the C code. It's called `flood_fill` in the module API.

```
#define RAVEL_INDEX(tuple, h) ( \
    (int)PyLong_AsLong(PyTuple_GetItem(tuple, 0)) + \
    h * (int)PyLong_AsLong(PyTuple_GetItem(tuple, 1)) \
)
#define N_OFFSETS 8

static PyObject *algorithms_flood_fill(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    PyObject *image_obj;
    PyObject *start_obj;
    int seed_value;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!O!i", &PyArray_Type, &image_obj,
                                         &PyTuple_Type, &start_obj,
                                         &seed_value)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Error parsing input");
        return NULL;
    }
    PyArrayObject *image_array;
    image_array = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_FROM_OTF(image_obj,
                                                   NPY_INT,
                                                   NPY_ARRAY_IN_FARRAY);
    if (image_array == NULL) {
        // Py_XDECREF(image_array);
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Couldn't parse the input array");
        return NULL;
    }
    int h = (int)PyArray_DIM(image_array, 0);
    int w = (int)PyArray_DIM(image_array, 1);
    intptr_t start_index = (intptr_t)RAVEL_INDEX(start_obj, h);
    // it should be safe to use PyArray_DATA as we ensured aligned contiguous Fortran array
    int *image = (int *)PyArray_DATA(image_array);
    size_t image_size = h * w;
    int offsets[N_OFFSETS] = {-(h+1), -h, -(h-1), -1, +1, h-1, h, h+1};
    flood_fill(image, offsets, N_OFFSETS, start_index, seed_value, image_size);
    Py_DECREF(image_array);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

If I give it a 9x9 array of integers initialized to 0 with a row of 1 in the middle (row index 4), `int offsets[] = {-10, -9, -8, -1, 1, 8, 9, 10}`, `size_t n_offsets = 8` `size_t start_index = 0`, `int new_value = 3`, `size_t image_size = 81`, all the 0 in the array get replaced by 3, which isn't the intended behavior.

```
import numpy as np
from mymodule import flood_fill

a = np.zeros((9, 9), order='F', dtype=np.int32)
a[4, :] = 1

flood_fill(a, (0, 0), 3)

# output :
# array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Is there something wrong with either the `queue` implementation or the `flood fill algorithm` logic itself or maybe the way it is called by the Python wrapper that could cause this problem ?

Comment: You should check the lower bound of the indices you're accessing. ` if (neighbor_index < image_size) {` in floodfill.c is not sufficient because `neighbor_index = current_index + offsets[i];` and some offsets can be negative.

Comment: Why post [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77366885/5459839)?

Comment: @wLui155 I set `neighbor_index` as a `size_t` so I hought it shouldn't be necessary to check if it is positive, I did implement the test for completness but it doesn't change anything

Comment: But did you read the comments there? They pointed out the error. You identify the right most cell as neighbor of the next row's left cell. Surely not right. This kind of thing would show up if you debugged your code with a debugger and small input.

Comment: @trincot not sure I understand, in Fortran order, the 8 neighbors of a cell should be  at {-(h+1), -h, -(h-1), -1, +1, h-1, h, h+1} relative from the current index, shouldn't they ?

Comment: Yes, and how many neighbors does a cell have in row 2 and column 0? Do you see the problem with this relative h-1?

Comment: In the Fortran code you had a separate check on the x-coordinate and y-coordinate (`if (in < 1 .or. in > imax) cycle`  and `if (jn < 1 .or. jn > jmax) cycle`). In this c code you don't have the same. You only check for exceeding the number of cells.

Comment: Yes because I was under the impression that size_t can't be negative and my understanding is that trying to make it negative should actually make it evaluate to MAX_INT so testing only that it is below image_size was sufficient... but perhaps this is wrong

Comment: @YeO For clarification: `(size_t) -1` is [`SIZE_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_library_type_aliases).

Comment: @Oka thanks, but it is a large positive value, right?

Comment: Yes, it is (and one would generally expect it to be *much* larger than `INT_MAX`).

Comment: The `size_t` type is one thing, but my comments are about something else. Say you have a 4x4 matrix, so with cell numbers 0 to 15: the second row has cells 4 to 7. Ask yourself: which are the neighbors of cell 4? Is cell 3 a neighbor of cell 4? The answer is no, so you shouldn't consider `-1` as a valid offset to add to this cell 4.

Comment: @trincot well, in Fortran order the second row has indices 1, 5, 9, 13 but I see your point yes, I think I generalized the neighbors offsets a bit too hastily and didn't give it a second thought. Thanks for your patience in pointing this out

Comment: I am not referring to your Fortran code now. There you have done it correctly. But you didn't apply that logic to your c implementation.

Comment: Another thing: if `h` really is the *height* of your image, i.e. the number of *rows*, then your offsets are wrong too. You should use `w` in your offset expressions, not `h`.

Comment: @trincot I'm still using a Fortran ordered array in the C code, that's why I'm insisting but that's not important, in the Fortran code, I did use the 2d array as it is so the neighbors indices are easier to check (but require more tests), I tried my luck at reading the array as 1d here because I'm accessing the array buffer, I thought I got it under controlled and tripped... and it took me a while to understand where... well, I guess that's how you learn ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with an image stored as a 1D array, you need more complex logic to check whether the neighbors are valid.

Try something like this:

```c
    // C implementation of floodfill algorithm
    
    //offset indexes are [upleft,up,upright,left,right,downleft,down,downright]
    const int UP_LEFT=0,UP=1,UP_RIGHT=2,LEFT=3,RIGHT=4,DOWN_LEFT=5,DOWN=6,DOWN_RIGHT=7;
    
    int valid_neighbour(int current_index, int dim, int offset_index){
        
        // first column
        if(current_index%dim==0
            && (offset_index==UP_LEFT
                ||offset_index==LEFT
                ||offset_index==DOWN_LEFT)){
            return 0;
        }
        
        //last column
        if(current_index%dim==dim-1
            && (offset_index==UP_RIGHT
                ||offset_index==RIGHT
                ||offset_index==DOWN_RIGHT)){
            return 0;
        }
        
        //first row
        if(current_index/dim==0
            && (offset_index==UP_LEFT
                ||offset_index==UP
                ||offset_index==UP_RIGHT)){
            return 0;
        }
        
        //last row
        if(current_index/dim==dim-1
            && (offset_index==DOWN_LEFT
                ||offset_index==DOWN
                ||offset_index==DOWN_RIGHT)){
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    
    int flood_fill(int* image, int* offsets, int n_offsets,
                   int start_index, int new_value, int image_size,int image_dim) {
        
        int current_index, neighbor_index;
    
        // Get the seed value (image value at start location)
        int seed_value = image[start_index];
        // Short circuit to avoid infinite loop
        if (seed_value == new_value) {
            return 0;
        }
        //image[start_index] = new_value;
        // Initialize the queue and push start position
        queue q = init_queue();
        push_queue(q, &start_index);
        
        // Break loop if all queued positions were evaluated
        while (pop_queue(q, &current_index)) {
            //Don't process already processed pixels
           if(image[current_index]==new_value){
               continue;
           }
           image[current_index]=new_value;
           printf("curr index: %d\n",current_index);
           
            // Look at all neighbors
            for (int i = 0; i < n_offsets; ++i) {
                neighbor_index = current_index + offsets[i];
                if (neighbor_index < image_size && neighbor_index>=0) {
                    
                    if (image[neighbor_index] == seed_value && valid_neighbour(current_index,image_dim,i)) {
                        // Process neighbor and push to queue
                        //image[neighbor_index] = new_value;
                        push_queue(q, &neighbor_index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Ensure memory is released
        free_queue(q);
        return 0;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int image[] = {
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
        };
        int offsets[] = {-10, -9, -8, -1, 1, 8, 9, 10};
        int n_offsets = 8;
        int start_index = 0;
        int seed_value = 3;
        int image_size = 81;
        int image_dim=9;
    
        flood_fill(image, offsets, n_offsets, start_index, seed_value, image_size,image_dim);
        
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                printf("%d ",image[i*9+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**: I used `int` instead of `size_t`, change it later.

Comment: Thanks, with regards to the optimisation, I actually thought that by setting the neighbor to `new_value` before pushing it to the queue was actually preventing a lot of cells to be pushed multiple times to the queue because they would be rejected by the test `== seed_value` whereas your implementation might push the same cell several times (but, granted, will shortcircuit after the first update)... again, I can be wrong

Comment: I accepted your answer, but for what it's worth, I stand by my remarks on optimization, setting the neighbor to new before pushing to the queue is the way to go. On the 9x9 array example provided, my code (credit goes to `scikit-image` and their implementation) pushes 36 cells which is the exact amount of cells that needed to be filled whereas yours pushes 108 cells to the queue (and discards them correctly), that's a lot of duplicates!

Comment: Okay. I was in a hurry and editing and running the code multiple times, probably a miscalculation on my part. I edited the answer.